# Is it possible to catch a signal in Octave/MATLAB?

Tags: signals, octave

I'm attempting to create a service in Octave where the user can define their own "triggers" / "listeners".  As an example I wanted to build a listener that would trap a specific signal (something like `10` / `SIGUSR1`) and perform the task of the service upon receipt of the signal, but I can't seem to find a way to trap a signal.

At this point I'm going to use a different way to demonstrate the flexibility of the service, but I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to trap signals in Octave.

UPDATE: I'd like to be able to catch the signal from a ".m" file and not an oct or mex file.

Comment: I think this is so special that you should ask on the Octave help mailinglist. Do you want to catch the signal in a "M-file" or in an oct or mex file?

Comment: I was hoping to catch the signal from an .m file.  I'll update the question.